# Writing meaningful unit tests for code with floating point inaccuracies (e.g. collision detection)

Tags: unit-testing, floating-point, physics-engine

Let's say I'm writing a physics engine with collision detection, using floats. One method might be to check if two physics objects are intersecting or touching.

```
class PhysicsObject {

    Vector3f position;

    [...]

    public void isIntersecting(PhysicsObject otherObject) {
        boolean isTouchingOrIntersecting = [do calculations];
        return isTouchingOrIntersecting;
    }

}
```

For the simulation itself, the floating point precision (even when using floats) is good enough because any inaccuracies will not be visible/noticeable (and immediately corrected in the next simulation step).

**But how should I write my unit tests, especially for the boundary cases?** I can write tests with two objects far away, and two objects clearly intersecting, but how about them touching exactly? Depending on the float values, the method could return true or false depending on any kind of external condition (compiler, architecture, etc.).

Or should I say that it is not important which result the method returns in this boundary case and so it makes no sense to write a unit test for this case?

When the method's return value is again a float, it's clear that I should use relative errors and epsilons. But I'm using this collision detection problem as an example for the whole class of similar problems when floating points are translated to some "exact" (boolean, integer) result, and how to test those (in the context of 3D graphics / physics code).

Answer (score 2):

IEEE arithmetic is not stochastic. It is reproducible bit-for-bit. So if it works on one machine and compiler, it will work on others, with a caveat.
The value of FLT_EVAL_METHOD={0,1,2} will produce different results due to differences in the precision of intermediate computations. You can use #ifdefs

```
#if FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 0
  EXPECT_EQ(answer0, result);
#elif FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 1
  EXPECT_EQ(answer1, result);
#else /* FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2 */
  EXPECT_EQ(answer2, result);
#endif
```

to sort between these different results. Unfortunately, when you use floating-point computations to make a decision, this is the only way. The good news is that a 3-way switch is sufficient. I have a few unit tests that do just that, and they perform flawlessly on many machines & compilers.

You can do the same thing for floating point comparisons, but if you only care about approximate equality, you can use something like googletest's EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(a,b), which checks for equality within 4 ULPs (units in the last position). The way this works is by first interpreting (using a union) the floating-point value as a signed magnitude integer, converting this to an excess-XX integer (merging ±0), then checking if the difference is <= 4. This automatically produces a relative measure that degrades into an absolute measure near zero.

Make sure that you use similar kinds of computations to determine *whether* and *where* there is an intersection. In fact, write a unit test to assure just that, and check it at the boundary, adjusting the location by ±1, ±2, ... ULPs to make sure that they are consistent. If the intersection query indicates true, but the location computations diverge because you can't find an intersection, you may end up in an infinite loop or crashing.